# How to divide screen with three different-sized panel in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sdk-2.3

i want to create a screen like this on the android :

and achieving this, i write some codes like that.. But i didn't do what i want. The text area doesn't exist in the screen. What should i do ? Any opinion.. thank you in advance..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout123" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        android:gravity="fill">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" >

     <Button android:id="@+id/button1"              
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"                                          
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
         android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />

        </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="118dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

         <Button android:id="@+id/button2"              
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"                                          
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
         android:text="Hello, I am a Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="228dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left" >

           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/text2"              
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"             
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"              
                android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />

           </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This depends on how you want this structured. If you want LinearLayouts so that you can add additional views to it or if you just want one button in each section and the one text view in the other

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A RelativeLayout will accomplish what you want

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rightLayout"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="#003300"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rightLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#330033"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/rightLayout"
        android:layout_below="@id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#334433"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The result as LinearLayouts and as Buttons/TextViews (since I wasn't sure which you wanted):

[image: Result] [image: Result2]

If you are using the LinearLayouts as a container to hold multiple views then leave it as I have it.

If you plan on having only one view in each of your "parts" change the LinearLayouts in my layout file to that type. 
Ex. if you want Part 1 to be just a button change

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
```

to be

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
```

Nested views are bad so its good to avoid them if you can

Comment: Thank you so much this is what i want.. As i mentioned, i want to seperate them because different applications will be in the each panel. For example in the first part there will be some text that is animeted, there will be photos or something in the third part. I think i can do this kind of application with these three layouts..

Answer (score 1):

you could :

```
Main linear layout with vertical alignment
add a new linear layout with horizontal alignment
add a new linear layout with horizontal or vertical alignment
```

So in the first layout ( the left part of main layout) you add a new linear layout with horizontal alignment and add the two elements you want. 
In the second layout ( the right part of main layout) you add a new linear layout or directly the object you want to show

Comment: If i didn't understand wrongly, you mean that the first and third part should be together. But i want to seperate them because different applications will be in the each panel. For example in the first part there will be some text, but in the third part there will be photos..

Comment: don't use relative layout.. it will be different in function of different screen size!! if you follow what i wrote you could add what u want to the layout..